# Line integral of a vector field over a intersection of a cylinder and a plane

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vector-fields, line-integrals

I need help calculating the line integral of this vector conservative field

$F(x,y,z)=(2xyz^2, x^2z^2+zcos(yz), 2x^2yz+ycos(yz))$

Compute

$\oint_{c}^{} Fds$

Where C is the intersection of the cylinder $\frac{x^2+y^2}{25}=1$ and the plane x+z=2.

Comment: There's a trick here, take another look at $F.$

Comment: is it about it being a coservative field?

Comment: Yep, it's conservative. So FTLI

Comment: I know how to apply the FTLI when they give me the starting and ending points, but i'm having trouble here

Comment: Pick any point on the contour $\vec{r}_0.$ This is also your ending point. What is $f(\vec{r}_0) - f(\vec{r}_0)$?

Comment: Do you realize your boundary is a closed curve? What is the line integral of a conservative vector field over a closed curve?

Comment: It's 0. I feel so silly now. But thanks a lot for the help!